# Understanding Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to understand the results of a Linear Discriminant Analysis.
For that purpose I used the Iris dataset.

I plotted the two first features:

[image]

Then, I projected these two features in the new subspace calculated by LDA:

```
model = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2,priors=None)
model.fit(X,iris.target)
X_projected = model.transform(X)
```

And I got the following plot:

[image]

Then I print the explained variance ratio to check which component contains more information regarding class separation:

```
print(model.explained_variance_ratio_)
```

And I got:

```
[0.96284253 0.03715747]
```

Which means the first component has 96% of the variance (almost the total).

So, I understand that in the projected space the new component New X1 contains almost all the variance, **but I don't know if that means that Sepal length is more class discriminant than Sepal Width.**